# How to Manipulate SQL Variable Twice in Single Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I am trying to truncate a date entry that includes the time data and set change its variable name in a single select statement.

```
SELECT Database.Schema.Variable AS newVariableName AS date
```

Here the variable outputs as `2017-12-28T09:17:15.250Z`, but I would like it to output `2017-12-28`.

I'm currently getting a `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'` error...

Comment: Try to use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`

Comment: I tried ```cast(Database.Schema.Variable AS newVariableName) AS date``` and the error was ```Type "Variable" is not a defined system type```.

Comment: With convert the error was ```The type name 'Variable' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.```

Comment: `SELECT CAST(Database.Schema.Variable AS DATE) AS newVariableName `

Comment: @Sami  This compiles, but returns ```2017-12-28T09:17:15.250Z```, not ```2017-12-28```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  SELECT cast(Database.Schema.Variable AS date) as newVariableName
```

Comment: This compiles, but returns ```2017-12-28T09:17:15.250Z```, not ```2017-12-28```.

Comment: It does not return time part. Could you recheck the code?

Comment: Hm, this is working in Management Studio, but not the web app that calls the function.  I'm probably running into cache issues on the app side.  Will mark as correct...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Database.Schema.Variable, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-us') AS newVariableName
```

The page says it applies to Transact SQL but I ran a quick test on a datetime field from my db and was good to go:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

For SQL-Server 2008:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Database.Schema.Variable, 111) AS newVariableName
```

Was found here:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: Received the following error: ```'format' is not a recognized built-in function name```

Comment: What database are you using?  This worked in sql-server 2014